# How do I link html files using android eclipse and webview?

Tags: android, eclipse, hyperlink

I have managed create my first android app following this Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVqp1zcMfbE.

However, i want to add more than one (30 html files) into the app in the same way. The normal way linking html

```
<a href="nextlink.html">title</a>
```

don't seem to work

I have search but find noting to indicate otherwise. what am i missing ?

I am using eclipse and android SDK on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your html files in assets folder of your project. If folder is not present named as assets then create one parallel to src folder of your project then paste all your html file into that and follow the belo code.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

Comment: Sadiq, thank you, i am past that point. See attached image for my problem. I want the index.html to link to the emergency.html and Vice Versa "via" a href links in the html. but when they app runs on my phone and i click the menu item the phone takes me to a screen where it says (the file must have been removed or deleted) [link](http://about.za.org/stack-flow-1.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

You can override url loading and load html pages manually:

```
final WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url) {
      webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/" + url);

      // Return true to override url loading.
      return true;
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    webview.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
}
```

Solution 2: 
Since your html files are in www-subfolder, you should use

```
<a href="/www/nextlink.html">title</a>
```

Comment: I think i am not communicating my problem. with your answer it means i have to do your solution 30 times over, for the other 28 pages i have not even started t create yet? I just want to know how come the normal html link don't work inside the html when it is compiled as n apk ? Thank you for your answer but it means nothing to me what you have written.,  As i am sure you can see by the elvel of the video i included i am new to this

Comment: You don't need to create individual WebViewClient for each page. If you want to load pages from href links then you have to write your own ContentProvider. This is easiest and cleanest solution.